# Test if a function name includes string, if the function returns an observable

Tags: javascript, typescript

I would like to decide which function of a subset of functions to use on the base of its name.

For Example:

```
methodArray = [method1() {},
               secondMethod() {},
               thirdMethod() {}]

getTheRightMethod(i: string){
 for (const method of methodArray) {
   if (method.name.includes(i)) {
     return method;
   }
 }
}

getTheRightMethod('second');
```

The result should be the `secondMethod()` in this case.

**Extra Question**
My next Problem is here that my functions return Observables. What I want is an array of pointers to the functions. Is this possible?

Comment: You probably mean function name. Your code should work if you pass named functions to it. What is the current problem? you probably meant to pass just the functions,  but your syntax is incorrect

Comment: `method1() {}` is a syntax error…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to declare named functions for this to work:

```js
const methodArray = [function one() { return 1; }, function two() { return 2; }, function three() { return 3; }];

function getRightMethod(str) {
  for (const method of methodArray) {
    if (method.name.includes(str)) {
      return method;
    }
  }
  return null;
}

console.log(getRightMethod('two')());
```

Comment: Do you might know, how I can do that if the functions return Observables?

Comment: @Celina, if each method returns an observable, this technique is still valid, as the name of the functions in the array won't change, only their return values

Comment: I found my mistake! I set my methodArray like this
`this.methodArray = [method1(), secondMethod()]` instead of  `= [method1, secondMethod] `
Thanks for your hint!

Answer (score 0):

The following would fix your syntax error by making them named functions and your code should work.

```
methodArray = [
       function method1() {},
       function secondMethod() {},
       function thirdMethod() {}
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is very close, with just a adjustments needed:

```js
/* Declare each "method" function in the array */
let methodArray = [
  function method1() {
    alert('first item')
  },
  function secondMethod() {
    alert('second item')
  },
  function thirdMethod() {
    alert('third item')
  }
];

function getTheRightMethod(i) {
  /* Iterate through array searching for first match */
  for (const method of methodArray) {
    /* Add missing ) after includes(i) */
    if (method.name.includes(i)) {
      return method;
    }
  }
}

/* Demonstrate this works by calling returned function */
getTheRightMethod('second')();
```